# Creating a boot iso image from a file

Tags: boot, iso

I have written a boot code that I want to run in VMware player. How can I create a disk iso image whose boot sector is my boot code on ubuntu?

Comment: about the boot code you wrote, what is the bootable device for your boot code? It's CD/DVD or HDD?

Comment: it is just a file. I want to create a disk image from that file and put the code in the first sector.

Comment: please try it with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you `genisoimage` or `mkisofs` command with `-b` and `-no-emul-boot` options.

I tried it with -b option as like following command.

```
genisoimage -no-emul-boot -b bootcode.bin -o test.iso testdir
```

I referenced that from the man page of genisoimage. Also you can see it with the command that `man genisoimage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `genisoimage` to create iso image from a file or directory

```
genisoimage -o output.iso directoryorfilepath
```

Change output name to name you want

Specify your directory or file path

Explain :

```
-o filename
              Specify  the  output  file for the the ISO9660 filesystem image.
              This can be a disk file, a tape  drive,  or  it  can  correspond
              directly  to the device name of the optical disc writer.  If not
              specified, stdout is used.  Note that the output can also  be  a
              block  device  for  a  regular disk partition, in which case the
              ISO9660 filesystem can be mounted normally to verify that it was
              generated correctly.
```

Comment: nux, sorry, -o option is just for create an iso image without bootable.  I think that -G or -b option is useful.